# Formik Yup validation on multiple select field (dropdown) react-form not working

Tags: reactjs, validation, select, formik, yup

I want to apply validation for the multi-select drop-down in React formik form. I successfully used validation while clicking on submit button

https://imgbox.com/3rSTa7GH

When I select multiple options from the select dropdown and deselect all values from the dropdown. At that time validation is not working.

https://imgbox.com/IkXmmGKj

https://imgbox.com/frLeTzWw

Below is the link for select drop-down coding standards
https://imgbox.com/ekLsAoXu

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please paste code, not image links.